# Accessing object value in array from json in node route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, embedded-javascript

How can access an object value in an array? Specifically "namecase" value? I have a ejs view looping in the array so that it can display all my object values. I'm passing data through routes.

```
//data.json
{
  "works": [{
    "company" : "Company 1",
    "projects": [{
      "namecase":"Projectname 1",
      "desc":"This is a project with fairies.",
      "img" : "/images/placeholder.jpg",
      "url" : "/" 
      },
      {
      "namecase":"Projectname 2",
      "desc":"This is a project with monsters.",
      "img" : "/images/placeholder.jpg",
      "url" : "/" 
      }]
      }

  ]

}

//index.js route

var appdata = require('../data.json');

router.get('/work', function(req, res) {
    var myProjects = [];
    appdata.works.forEach ( function (item){
//this is where I pull object from json
        myProjects = myProjects.concat(item.projects["namecase"]);
    });
  res.render('work', { 
    title: 'Work',
    projects: myProjects
  });
});

///ejs

    <% if (projects.length > 0) { %>
    <% for (i=0; i<projects.length; i++) { %>

    <span><%= projects["namecase"] %></span>


    <% }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to concat `item.projects`, not the `namecase` key as you're doing. Also, once you're in the `works` object's `projects` child object, you'll want to loop through the projects and *then* concat them, like so:

```
router.get('/work', function(req, res) {
  var myProjects = [];
  appdata.works.forEach(function(work) {
    // Loop through each project to prevent undefined indices from being concatenated
    work.projects.forEach(function(project) {
      myProjects = myProjects.concat(project);
    });
  });
  res.render('work', { 
    title: 'Work',
    projects: myProjects
  });
});
```

Doing so will return just the projects:

```
[ { namecase: 'Projectname 1',
    desc: 'This is a project with fairies.',
    img: '/images/placeholder.jpg',
    url: '/' },
  { namecase: 'Projectname 2',
    desc: 'This is a project with monsters.',
    img: '/images/placeholder.jpg',
    url: '/' } ]
```